# Why circle is also getting bigger on zoom?

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose

```
var centroid by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var zoom by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
    val decimalFormat = remember { DecimalFormat("0.0") }

    var transformDetailText by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            "Use pinch gesture to zoom in or out.\n" +
                    "Centroid is position of center of touch pointers"
        )
    }


    val imageModifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures(
                onGesture = { gestureCentroid, _, gestureZoom, _ ->
                    centroid = gestureCentroid
                    val newZoom = zoom * gestureZoom
                    zoom = newZoom.coerceIn(0.5f, 5f)

                    transformDetailText = "Zoom: ${decimalFormat.format(zoom)}, centroid: $centroid"
                }
            )
        }
        .graphicsLayer {
            scaleX = zoom
            scaleY = zoom
        }
        .drawWithContent {
            drawContent()
            drawCircle(color = Color.Red, center = centroid, radius = 20f)
        }
```

Why circle is also getting bigger on zoom in, According to me, first graphic layer zooms the image after then "drawWithContent" should draw a circle of 20f radius, but circle is changing shape on zooming in and out